# Publications Mathématiques de l'IHÉS

Tags: fonts

I would like to know which font is used by Publications Mathématiques de l'IHÉS. For example 
in this paper:

[enter link description here](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/PMIHES/PMIHES_2007__106_/PMIHES_2007__106__139_0/PMIHES_2007__106__139_0.pdf)

Or perhaps the right question is which style they used?

Thanks for answering and helping.

Comment: Well, according to the PDF info, the document combines Baskerville and Times New Roman ... for whatever reason.

Comment: The font is BaskervilleMT, with a proprietary accompanying math font. Times is used, quite surprisingly, in math for the operator names (the `log` at the bottom of the first page). Also some MathTime fonts are used for some math symbols. The fake small caps are a punch in the eye.